# Word document doesn't close properly

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dynamic, ms-word

Data dynamically populating from drop-down list correctly; however, how may I get the Word document to close properly in between each entry?

Problem:

The Word document doesn't close properly in between each new entry in the Excel dynamic drop-down list.

What is occurring:

The loop is executing over each hospital; however, Word isn't closing in between each new entity. Result is that all the addresses and tables are inserting without interruption.

What should occur:

Each hospital with it's own unique data in a new Word document (attached, the Excel sheet "Table" has a drop-down in call B2 that autopopulates the table 1 and the hospital's address; the Word document has bookmarks to insert this data).

In advance, thank you very much for your expertise. I have tried various commands to close the active document in Word (not shown) but then cannot get Word to open up again with the template. Realize there is likely a simple solution to incorporate into the existing code.

Regards,
Karen

```
 Sub MMISPMT()
    
    Worksheets("table").Activate
    
    'Declare variables
    
    Dim WordApp As Object 
    Dim WordDoc As Object 
    Dim dvCell As Range   
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView 
    
    'Set variables
    'Which cell has data validation
    Set dvCell = Worksheets("Table").Range("B2")  'this is a drop-down box of entity name values that 
    populates address info and table 1 in Word document
    'Determine where validation comes from
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application ' based on the template ref'd in WordDoc
            
    'Word template to be used
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\<pathway>\letter.docx", NewTemplate:=False, 
    DocumentType:=0)
    
    'Begin loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each c In inputRange
     dvCell = c.Value
     MsgBox dvCell
     Debug.Print dvCell 
    
    Dim table1 As Range
    Dim HosName As Range
    Dim address1 As Range
    Dim city As Range
    Dim zip As Range
    
    'Declare variables
    
    Set table1 = Range("a10:g15")
    Set HosName = Range("b2")
    Set address1 = Range("ad5")
    Set city = Range("ad6")
    Set zip = Range("ad7")
    
    HosName.Select
    Selection.Copy
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("HosName").Select
    Set objSelection = WordApp.Selection
    objSelection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
    
    address1.Select
    Selection.Copy
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("address1").Select
    Set objSelection = WordApp.Selection
    objSelection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
    
    
    city.Select
    Selection.Copy
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("city").Select
    Set objSelection = WordApp.Selection
    objSelection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
    
    
    zip.Select
    Selection.Copy
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("zip").Select
    Set objSelection = WordApp.Selection
    objSelection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
    
    
    table1.Select
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("table1").Select
    Set objSelection = WordApp.Selection
    objSelection.Paste
    
    'Generate the Word template per hospital with data
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\<pathway>\" & HosName & " " & Format((Year(Now() + 1) 
    Mod 100), "20##") & _
            Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "0#") & _
            Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#") & "-report.docx", _
                                   FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument 
            
    Next c
    
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to open the template at the top of the loop, then save and close the document at the bottom of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the template at the top of the loop, then save and close the document at the bottom of the loop.

Also you can tidy up your code by factoring the copy/paste into a separate method.

```
Sub MMISPMT()
    
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range, wsTable As Worksheet
    
    Set wsTable = Worksheets("Table")
    Set dvCell = Worksheets("Table").Range("B2")
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)
    
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application ' based on the template ref'd in WordDoc
            
    For Each c In inputRange.Cells
    
    
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\<pathway>\letter.docx", _
                                            NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
        dvCell = c.Value
        
        CopyToBookmark wsTable.Range("B2"), WordDoc, "HosName"
        CopyToBookmark wsTable.Range("AD5"), WordDoc, "address1"
        CopyToBookmark wsTable.Range("AD6"), WordDoc, "city"
        CopyToBookmark wsTable.Range("AD7"), WordDoc, "zip"
        CopyToBookmark wsTable.Range("A10:G15"), WordDoc, "table1", False
        
        WordDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\<pathway>\" & HosName & " " & _
                               Format((Year(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "20##") & _
                               Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "0#") & _
                               Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#") & "-report.docx", _
                                   FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
        WordDoc.Close
    
    Next c
    
End Sub

'transfer/copy data from a Range into a named bookmark in doc
'   either directly as text or copy/paste as table
Sub CopyToBookmark(rng As Range, doc As Word.document, bmk As String, _
                   Optional AsValue As Boolean = True)
    If AsValue Then
        doc.bookmarks(bmk).Range.Text = rng.Value
    Else
        rng.Copy
        doc.bookmarks(bmk).Range.Paste
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, thank you so much! Those missing elements are so helpful as is the extra cleanup steps! You made my year :)